# Rotating CIImage by angle & Core Image coordinate system

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-image, ciimage

I have some doubts about Core Image coordinate system, way transforms are applied and extent is determined. I couldn't find much in documentation or on internet so I tried the following code to rotate CIImage and display it in UIImageView.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    
    ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: (uiImage?.cgImage)!)
    imageView.image = uiImage
}

private var currentAngle = CGFloat(0)
private var ciImage:CIImage!
private var ciContext = CIContext()

  @IBAction func rotateImage() {
    
    let extent = ciImage.extent
    
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX, y: extent.midY)
    let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    
    currentAngle = currentAngle + CGFloat.pi/10
    
    let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: currentAngle)
    let translateBack = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -extent.midX, y: -extent.midY)
    
    let transform = translateBack.concatenating(rotate.concatenating(translate))
    
    ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: (uiImage?.cgImage)!)
    ciImage = ciImage.transformed(by: transform)
    
    NSLog("Extent \(ciImage.extent), Angle \(currentAngle)")
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
    
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

So as I rotate the image every time by the push of a button, the image is rotated by angle *pi/10* each time. But I see the image shrinking in UIImageView. The NSLogs show the extent is growing with some rotations with the origin x and y becoming negative.

```
  2021-09-24 14:43:29.280393+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Metal API Validation Enabled
  2021-09-24 14:43:31.094877+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-105.0, -105.0, 1010.0, 1010.0), Angle 0.3141592653589793
  2021-09-24 14:43:41.426371+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-159.0, -159.0, 1118.0, 1118.0), Angle 0.6283185307179586
  2021-09-24 14:43:42.244703+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-159.0, -159.0, 1118.0, 1118.0), Angle 0.9424777960769379
  2021-09-24 14:43:42.644446+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-105.0, -105.0, 1010.0, 1010.0), Angle 1.2566370614359172
  2021-09-24 14:43:43.037312+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 800.0), Angle 1.5707963267948966
  2021-09-24 14:43:43.478774+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-105.0, -105.0, 1010.0, 1010.0), Angle 1.8849555921538759
  2021-09-24 14:43:44.045811+0400 CoreImagePrototypes[65817:5175194] Extent (-159.0, -159.0, 1118.0, 1118.0), Angle 2.199114857512855
```

My questions:

1. How exactly do I determine scale factor to rescale the image so that the extent does not cross the original image rectangle?
2. What exactly does negative extent origin means? Relative to what it is negative? I understand coordinate system in Core Image is relative assuming bottom left corner of image to be (0,0), not with respect to some superview like in UIKit.

Comment: Are you just trying to rotate the image in place in the UI without affecting the original image, or are you trying to create a new image of the original image, but rotated?

Comment: As you can see in the code I am creating a new image in every call and replace in UI. The point of the exercise is understanding the coordinate space of Core Image and how extent property is affected by CGAffineTransform, why extent origin becomes negative? Relative to what it is negative?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You say `let extent = ciImage.extent` but that CIImage is not the one you actually apply the transforms to.

Comment: Yes @matt the extent property I use to do the rotation along the center of the image. But now from your answer as it appears that the extent is of bounding box, so with this understanding I need to rewrite code to rotate CIImage by arbitrary angle and fit it in the extent of original image.

Comment: You say "I need to rewrite code" but you have never explain what the goal of your code is. If your goal is to rotate around the center, then this is the same as for a UIView: you need to translate to the center, rotate, and translate back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what the question is, but what you seem to be focussed on is the meaning of the `extent`. This is like the frame, and, just like the frame, it loses its meaning if you have applied a transform to the CIImage. After a rotation, the `extent` is now based on the *bounding box* of the transformed image. So if you have a horizontally wider image and you rotate it a little bit counterclockwise, the `extent` becomes taller and its top becomes negative.

Comment: So to be clear, you are saying the origin of transformed image is still at the bottom left corner, but extent returned is of bounding box. The bounding box bottom left corner is further down and left of this image origin, hence the negative origin of bounding box!